# Disable {% debug %} tag in Django template

Tags: django, templates, jinja2

Is there a way to prevent Django template from outputting a bunch of debug output? I tried setting `DEBUG = False` and setting my `TEMPLATES` option like so:

```
TEMPLATES = [
  {
    ...
    'OPTIONS': {
      'debug': False,
      'context_processors': [
        'django.template.context_processors.request',
        'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
        'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
      ],
    }
  }
]
```

Despite the above settings, whenever I put `{% debug %}` into my template, it still outputs a lot of debug information.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an if statement in template tied to your settings.py Debug variable value and pass that value from your view.

**Your View**

```
from .settings import DEBUG
def your_view(request):
    context={‘debug_var’: DEBUG}
    return render (request, “template.html”,context )
```

**Your Template**

```
{% if debug_value %}

{% debug %}

{% else %}
<p>No debug </p>

{% endif %}
```